# Using or in a while loop (Python)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, logic

```
variable1 = 0
while variable1 != "1" or variable1 != "2" or variable1 != "3":
    variable1 = input ("Enter variable1: ")
print("Succes")
```

My code never goes out of the while loop even if the variable is assigned 1 or 2 or 3.
Am I missing something here or doing something wrong? I never read any documentation about Python that said or statements wouldn't work in while loops. According to propositional calculus this should be correct because True or False or False = True

I am aware that I did not use integers by the way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the `!= to` doing there? <ominous chanting> Kill the `to`! Kill the `to`! Kill the `to`! </ominous chanting>

Comment: What happens when variable1 = 'al;dfjakl;fkja;lkajdfj'?

Comment: `variable1 != to "1"` is a syntax error.  Why is the "to" in there?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget That's not supposed to be in there, a strange typo I made. I'll fix it.

Comment: @Joe Then it will be false and not work, asking for input again.

Comment: @zimano exactly. But what if variable1 is 1? The other two cases will still turn out to be true, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition of your while loop will ALWAYS be true. In order for it to be false, `variable1` must equal `"1"`, `"2"`, and `"3"`, which is impossible for a single string.

```
>>> variable1 == "1"
>>>
>>> variable1 != "1"
False
>>> variable1 != "2"
True
>>> variable1 != "3"
True
>>> False or True or True
True # So the loop will continue execution
```

Do you want your while loop to exit if `variable1` equals `"1"`, `"2"`, or `"3"`?

```
while not (variable1 == "1" or variable1 == "2" or variable1 == "3"):
```

If `variable1` equals either `"1"`, `"2"`, or `"3"`, then it's useful to imagine how the condition will be resolved:

```
while not (True or False or False):

while not (True):

while False: # Exit
```

Comment: How would I go around changing this around so that it will work? Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

The condition of your while-loop will *always* evaluate to `True` because `variable1` will always be not equal to `"1"` or not equal to `"2"`.

Instead, you will want to use [`not in`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in) here:

```
variable1 = 0
while variable1 not in ("1", "2", "3"):
    varible1 = input("Enter variable1: ")
print("Succes")
```

---

However, judging by your code structure, I think that you want `variable1` to be an integer, not a string.

If so, then you can use this on Python 3.x:

```
variable1 = 0
while variable1 not in (1, 2, 3):
    varible1 = int(input("Enter variable1: "))
print("Succes")
```

or, if you are on Python 2.x, you can use this:

```
variable1 = 0
while variable1 not in (1, 2, 3):
    varible1 = int(raw_input("Enter variable1: "))
print "Succes"
```

Comment: Would be better to use a set instead of a tuple, to optimize lookup time

Comment: I run it and never stops, shouldn't be `(1,2,3)`

Comment: @xndrme - Judging by his `print` syntax as well as the fact that he is comparing with strings to begin with, I am assuming that the OP is on Python 3.x.  If so, `input` will return a string object.

Comment: @iCodez Ok, I'm in 2.7, my mistake :(

Comment: @inspectorG4dget - Actually, with so few choices, the time difference is negligible.  In fact, if you test it with `timeit.timeit`, the set is slower (in this specific case).

Comment: True. But `set` scales a lot better. Of course, you're right that with such a small size, the overhead of creating the set itself will dominate any savings in lookup time

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: On modern Python 3's CPython reference interpreter, the `set` will perform better, but prior to 3.2, it would have performed worse (because it rebuilt the `set` prior to each test). It was only [optimized to make such tests against a `set` literal of constant literals build a `frozenset` at compile time and reuse it in 3.2](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations). The `set` would *always* lose prior to 3.2 though, since building the `set` would already be `O(n)`, so you didn't save anything over a direct scan of a `tuple` (which was always a constant).

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to update the variable in the while loop
2. If you use `input` you need to compare as `int`

---

```
variable1 = 0
while variable1 not in {1,2,3}:
    variable1 = input("Enter variable1: ")

print("Succes")
```

Comment: Would be better to use a set instead of a list, to optimize lookup time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'or', you should use 'and'.  You want to keep asking for input as long as the input is not a "1" AND it is not a "2" AND it is not a "3".

Comment: I'm not a Python programmer (yet).  While my answer is logically valid, the solution offered by @xndrme is more elegant.